# Printing the currently active window in landscape mode

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, landscape, powerpacks

I want to print the currently active `WinForm` in C#. Here is what I have:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Printing;

PrintForm p = new PrintForm(this);
p.Print();
```

This works great for **portrait** mode. How can I print in **landscape** mode?

Comment: I did a google search and came up with this 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.printing.compatibility.vb6.printer.orientation.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
PrintForm p = new PrintForm(this);
p.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
p.Print();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are doing this in VB then you want to look at Orientation as an example

if it's C# I am sure you can do the conversion

```
If p.Height > p.Width 
{
    p.Orientation = 1;//vbPRORPortrait
}
Else
{
    p.Orientation = 2; //vbPRORLandscape
}
p.Print();
```

Comment: p>orientation is not available in C#

Comment: if you are using Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Printing; that's saying that you are using a VisualBasic Assembly and you should be able to get at that property..

Comment: constant values: vbPRORPortrait = 1, vbPRORLandscape = 2